# Understanding recursive code

Tags: java

I need some help understanding the "behind the scenes" part of my code. I had a TA help me with part of the code so I'm not entirely sure what some of it does.

Here are my questions (I know you should post multiple questions separately, but these 2 go hand in hand and overall, this a pretty short question.)

1. Using the recursive method, write out the string that is being processed at each step if the word “radar” was entered. Do the same for “Straw arts”. So like a step by step breakdown of how the recursive method figures out that radar and straw arts are both palindromes.  So how would it look behind the scenes if I inputted radar into my program?

And then I just need some help using a short and simple iterative method to do the same thing for a palindrome:

2. Write some simple code using the iterative method (using loops) to solve this same problem. (The problem being - Implement a program which uses a recursive method that determines if a string entered by the user is a palindrome. A string is palindrome if it is the same forward as it is backwards, such as “radar” or “Taco cat”.)

Here is my code to solve using the recursive methode:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RecursivePalindrome {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a word and I will determine if it is a palindrome");//Gets user input
    String word = keyboard.nextLine();
    String combined = word.replaceAll("[\\W]", "");//matches non-word characters, and removes the spaces.
    combined = combined.toLowerCase();//makes the combined word all lowercase
    if(checkPalindrome(word))//calls palindrome method and sees if combined word is a palindrome
    {
        System.out.println("The word " +  word +  " is a palindrome");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("The word " + word + " is not a palindrome");
    }
}

private static boolean checkPalindrome(String word) 
{
    if(word.length() <= 1)//if length is less than or equal to 1 then the string is palindrome
    {
         return true;
    } 
    if(word.charAt(0) == word.charAt(word.length()-1))//checks the first and last char of the string
    {
        //if true, then does the same thing with substring
        //returns only when the string is done checking
        return checkPalindrome(word.substring(1, word.length()-1));
    }
    //if string doesn't pass check, it's not a palindrome
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: The fact that you don't have a '?' is one possible indication that your question is unclear. What are you asking? What don't you understand?

Comment: I need help with how straw arts and radar would be a palindrome while running my program.  So like a step by step breakdown of what my code does to the word radar to make it pass the palindrome test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first question may seem complicated but it aims for some well placed `System.out.println()` instruction within your recursive method.

The intended learning effect is, that you can see what is actually happen there.

Just place a `System.out.println(word)` in the beginning of the method. Then do it with more `System.out.println()` with eligible statements after every if statement.

To check it iterative you just have to check if the first letter is equal to the last letter, and the second letter is equal to the second letter from behind and so on:

```
public static boolean isPalindrom(String word){
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length() / 2; i++) {
        if(word.charAt(i) != word.charAt(word.length()-1-i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I appreciate it.

Comment: Aprreciate with error. Check case  “Taco cat”. return false.

Answer (score 0):

question 2), loop method

```
private static boolean checkPalindrome(String word) 
{
    int ii = 0;
    int io = word.length()-1;

    while(ii<io)
    { 
        if((word.charAt(ii) == ' ') ii++;
        else if((word.charAt(io) == ' ') io--;
        else if(Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(ii))
            != Character .toLowerCase(word.charAt(io))) return false;
        else { ii++; io--; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

recursive call:

```
boolean result = checkPalindrome(word, 0, word.lenght()-1);
```

proc

```
private static boolean checkPalindrome(String word, int ii, int io) 
{   
    while((ii<io)&&(word.charAt(ii) == ' ')) ii++; // skipp spaces
    while((io>ii)&&(word.charAt(io) == ' ')) io--; // skipp spaces
    if(ii>=io) return true;
    if(Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(ii))
        == Character .toLowerCase(word.charAt(io))) 
            return checkPalindrome(word, ii++, io--);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: complete method with any spaces

Comment: I'v add recursive version